# Does Clang promote shorts to integers when combined with number literals on ARM targets?

Tags: c, arm, signal-processing

Using GCC on the desktop with the `-Wconversion` warnings turned on, it becomes evident that `short`s get promoted to `int`s during math operations with number literals:

```
unsigned short i = 10; // Obviously truncates to short immediately
unsigned short j = 30; // Same here

i = j + 2; // Warnings imply j gets promoted to int here, demands cast
```

On ARM targets where the the rule thrown about is that "shorts are always faster", is it still true that during almost any math operation (especially including literals) they are promoted to `int`s for the operation?

If so, is there any reason to use `short`s other than they let the compiler help you check bounds are sensible? I'm not dealing with large quantities of shorts, so the storage space wouldn't seem to be an issue (or is it?).

NB. This is audio processing, so I'm not optimising for the sake of it and do need to think about this.

Comment: `+` operator promotes operands to int (for example if its `char`, or leas then `sizeof(int)`).

Comment: Where have you seen "shorts are always faster" about ARM? It's obviously bullshit, since they have to be truncated to 16 bits every time they get moved from a 32-bit register.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> On ARM targets where the the rule thrown about is that "shorts are always faster", is it still true that during almost any math operation (especially including literals) they are promoted to ints for the operation?

With most operators a `short` operand is promoted to `int` because of the integer promotion rule.

For example

```
i = j + 2;  // j is promoted to int because of integer promotion
```

but also

```
i = i + j; // i and j are promoted to int in the + expression
```

> On ARM targets where the the rule thrown about is that "shorts are always faster"

On ARM, `short` are `16`-bit but the ARM word size is `32`-bit, so this statement is wrong.  `short` or `char` need to be signed extended or zero extended and are slower.  `short` can be used to save memory but for performances `int` or `long` are faster.

Answer (score 2):

Arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than `int` as arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Formally, the language requires that types narrower than `int` are promoted (either to `int` or `unsigned int`) before most arithmetic operations.  This means that in your example, `j` is promoted to `int`, the addition is performed in an `int`, and the result is converted back to `short` by the assignment.

However, the compiler is free to elide these conversions *if it won't change the observable behaviour of the program*.  Since the result in this case is converted back to `short`, this applies here - the compiler could emit an instruction that directly performs the addition in the `short` size, and that would be legal.  If that would execute faster on the target platform, you can expect that `clang` would do so.